# Evaluate Expressions in Switch Statements in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have to implement the following in a `switch` statement:

```
switch(num)
{
  case 4:
    // some code ;
    break;
  case 3:
    // some code ;
    break;
  case 0:
    // some code ;
    break;
  case < 0:
    // some code ;
    break;
}
```

Is it possible to have the switch statement evaluate `case < 0`? If not, how could I do that?

Comment: In C# 9.0, your original switch statement will now compile! See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65685479/2787772

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Note: the answer below was written in 2009. Switch patterns were introduced in C# 7.

---

You can't - switch/case is only for individual values. If you want to specify conditions, you need an "if":

```
if (num < 0)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    switch(num)
    {
        case 0: // Code
        case 1: // Code
        case 2: // Code
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: or even switch(num) { case 0: case  1: default: if (num < 0) {..} }

Comment: @roe: Yes, I considered giving that form too. Ran out of time though :)

Comment: Am I right in thinking this *is* possible with VB.NET?

Comment: @Dave: Not sure - wouldn't be surprised though. (It may be available in a future version of C# too, at least to some extent, with the new pattern matching feature.)

Comment: Odd, I think I found one (see selected answer) http://stackoverflow.com/a/27372155/1221410 - Sorry, if I had found this first I woudn't have asked :)

Comment: It is possible since C#7. Please see the Max's answer below.

Comment: @DmitryKh: Yes, I'm well aware of that - this answer was written in 2009.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for updating your answer. Now it is not so confusing as it was to me yesterday. Also, it would be nice if you mentioned that the answer below has a modern example.

Comment: @DmitryKh: I'm afraid I don't have time to give detailed updates to over 30,000 answers over the course of 12 years. Anyone wanting to know more about switch patterns should be able to find more information pretty trivially with a quick search.

Answer (score 108):

I know that this topic is pretty old but if someone still looking for the answer now in C# 7 it's possible. Here is an example:

```
switch (value)
{
     case var expression when value < 0:
         //some code
         break; 

     case var expression when (value >= 0 && value < 5):
         //some code
         break;

     default:
         //some code
         break;
}
```

Comment: if `expression` is useless, you can replace `expression` with `_` on c#7.

Comment: @PoyChang I wouldn't call that useless I would call it more maintainable, anyone who doesn't know the syntax can derive the meaning when it says maintainable, however when it is an underscore some meaning is lost.

Comment: @HughWood The point of using underscore is to imply that the variable is meaningless, so no meaning is lost.  For example, you may use it as the argument to a Func<TParam, TResult> when you don't need the parameter. `_ => true`, or in this case when the variable is redundant with another variable and using both would be less maintainable.

Comment: This is a perfect example of reduced maintainability, and using this will result in lost time deciphering what it means, as it isn't and still isn't in common usage, and the knowledge distance between entry level and senior developers is quite extensive, it's sugar like this that costs businesses money. Ergo it's less maintainable, where clear variable names, and correctly commented code. The introduction of oversimplifying code in many extends is the sheer definition of unmaintainable code.

Comment: These days anyone should have at least some exposure to ML/Haskell languages, and there the `_` in pattern matching is idiomatic and one of the first things you learn. Heck, it's a thing in F#, and trying hard to avoid F# when it so beautifully interoperates with C# is IMHO nuts. Even for someone who hasn't seen it, it should be quite obvious I think that it's a placeholder, and that it's a valid identifier, so no biggie. It's nothing like use of `$` in identifiers in C++, where it's an omnipresent extension and not a requirement in the standard, and is not in widespread use anywhere.

Comment: This should be the selected answer nowadays..

Answer (score 55):

you can do this

```
switch (mark)
{
    case int n when n >= 80:
        Console.WriteLine("Grade is A");
        break;

    case int n when n >= 60:
        Console.WriteLine("Grade is B");
        break;

    case int n when n >= 40:
        Console.WriteLine("Grade is C");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Grade is D");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Glad I kept scrolling! Nice!

Comment: Could you add that a link to the pattern matching article, and that this was released in C# 7 (way later than the answer was posted)?

Answer (score 23):

In a twist of C# fate, this has come all the way back around. If you upgrade to C# 9.0, your original switch statement will now compile! C#9.0 has added Relational patterns to pattern matching in general, which includes switch statements.

You can now do some really funky stuff, like this:

```
      var num = new Random().Next();
      
      switch(num)
      {
        case < 0:
          // some code ;
          break;
        case 0:
          // some code ;
          break;
        case > 0 and < 10:
          // some code ;
          break;
        case > 20 or (< 20 and 15):
          // some code ;
          break;
      }
```

Note the use of literal 'and' and 'or' in the last case, to allow && and || type expressions to compile.

To use C# 9, make sure the XmlNode LangVersion is set to Latest or 9.0 in the csproj file, in a property group

e.g.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Mock</Configurations>
    <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Like the way C# is evolving as a modern language although being much more mature than today's modern languages.

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like this at the end of your switch statement:

```
default:
    if(num < 0)
    {
        ... // Code
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 10):

If your num can't be less than zero:

```
public int GetSwitch(int num) { return num < 0 ? -1 : num; }
switch(GetSwitch(num))
{
case 4: // some code ; break;
case 3:// some code ; break;
case 0: // some code ; break;
case -1 :// some code ; break;
}
```

If it can, use some other "non-existent" number such as int.MinValue.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest -- but why put the ternary in a different function?

Comment: interesting solution +1, although I personally feel the extra function call clutters the view a bit, `switch (num < 0 ? -1 : num)` just feels more explict.

Comment: I'm a big follower of SRP and DRY - so even unconsciously I separate one behavior from another unrelated behavior. GetSwitch(), for example, can be reused, and what if you need two switches - do you copy/paste your ternary into there? I don't consider copy/pasting a good practice.

Comment: Just name it GetMeaningfulSwitchName() (e.g. GetOrderTypeSwitch) and this will make more sense. Maybe even put this into the entity itself, like Order.GetTypeRank().

Comment: DRY is of course good, however actually repeating "GetSwitch(num)" is more repeating than num<0?-1:num (which is two characters less)... :) All jokes aside, I think in this case, not having the result of GetSwitch immediately deducable (e.g. if you're using it somewhere else as well) hurts more than helps. But that's only MHO.

Comment: Jokes aside, what is going to happen if your switch logic changes (e.g. -1 is now a valid number) and you need to use int.MinValue (or -2) instead of -1 as the switch number? Are you going to search and replace all the hard-coded switches? I really hate the copy/pasted code, and this is one of the reasons why - it's a nightmare to maintain. Another reason - it is not clear to read. GetOrderRankSwitch() can be _read_, while ternary doesn't tell anything. And you can't track in the sources (called by).

Comment: And by the way, the "num<0?-1:num" doesn't even contain spaces, if we talk about characters (which is not what DRY is about). Also, it seems that there're people who doesn't get the idea that function name expresses its intent, while immediate inline code rarely does. Getting this comment up-voted 2 times means more "maintenance from hell" work for some people.

Answer (score 9):

Enter 2021.

```csharp
var res = num switch
{
    4 => "It's four",
    3 => "It's three",
    0 => "It's zero",
    < 0 => "It's negative",
    _ => "It's something else"
};
```

Boom.

*(To be fair, [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) are a C# 8.0 feature, so not really 2021. But still few people seem to know about it.)*

Comment: and amazingly speaking VB.net has the "Case Is > 0" since ever ... it's about time for C# to have it too (i'm not among the "people seem to know about it" - now i do)

Comment: Just a quick note: while switch expressions are available from c#8, numerical evaluations are only available from C#9.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to use if, wether you want or not. Switch is only capable of comparing your value to constant values.

Comment: Not true -- you can use a ternary operator to consolidate the less-than-zero case into a single value, and evaluate that in the switch.

Comment: This is true. It's just a restriction of the language. You can actually do this in VB.Net, as well as other things like using value ranges. Like C#, if has to compare against literal value, but there are more compare operations available.

Comment: Really Charles? Interesting. I did not know that.

Comment: Just to be nit-picky, saying "constant values (literals)" is an error. You were doing great right up until the parenthetical. The parenthetical implies that "literals" and "constant values" are *synonyms* when in fact literal constants are a *subset* of constant values. All literals are constants, but not all constants are literals. The switch statement requires constants, but does not require literals.

Comment: @Andy - yes, the VB "select/case" is much more powerful and flexible than the C# "switch/case".  Although I see that you can now do a "switch" on strings in C# - couldn't do that in C/C++, IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I could think of (and I really don't recommand it), would be as follows:

```
int someValue;

switch (Math.Max(someValue, -1))
{
    case -1:
        // will be executed for everything lower than zero.
        break;

    case 0:
       // will be executed for value 0.
       break;

    case 1:
       // will be executed for value 1.
       break;

    default:
       // will be executed for anything else.
       break;
}
```

Comment: Why not just Math.Max(someValue, -1) ? Then he doesn't need to worry about the +1 offset...

Comment: I think it's bad style too, so I stated in my answer that i really don't recommand that way. And Math.Max(x, -1) is really better than 0.

Comment: @Oliver: probably because your code is pretty close to obfuscation. It's not immediately visible what's happening here. The other solutions provided here are much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

The other way around would be possible also (relating to Jon Skeet's answer):

```
switch(num)
{
  case a:
      break;
  default:
      if( num < 0 )
      {}
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is to use a delegate like this.

```
        var actionSwitch = new Dictionary<Func<int, bool>, Action>
        {
             { x => x < 0 ,     () => Log.Information("less than zero!")},
             { x => x == 1,     () => Log.Information("1")},
             { x => x == 2,     () => Log.Information("2")},
             { x => x == 3,     () => Log.Information("3")},
             { x => x == 4,     () => Log.Information("4")},
             { x => x == 5,     () => Log.Information("5")},
        };

        int numberToCheck = 1;

        //Used like this
        actionSwitch.FirstOrDefault(sw => sw.Key(numberToCheck)).Value();
```

Just swap out what you wan´t to perform where the Log.Information("x") is and you have your "switch" statement.

You will need to some error handling if you check for a key that is "found" by the Func.

If you like to see the Func version of the switch I just wrote a [blog post with Switch example chapter](https://sturla.io/func-and-action-delegate-examples/).

But if you can use C# 7 it will give you [better switch capabilities](https://github.com/sturlath/Sturla.io.Func/blob/f4402dc1729b6c904ea12a64689a721e27ac7f4c/SwitchExample/Switch.Console/Program.cs#L91).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use comparisons in switches like you could in VB, you have 2 options here, replace the value you switch on with a known value and use that or - if you mean all other cases - you can use the default clause:

```
switch(num)
{
  case 4:
    // some code ;
    break;
  case 3:
    // some code ;
    break;
  case 0:
    // some code ;
    break;
  default:
    // some code ;
    break;
}
```

Note that this does not exactly like you asked for: any values other than 0,3,4 will end up in the deafult: clause.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the following pattern recently, and while I abhor it, I can't argue that it's not practical:

```
switch(0)
{
  case 0 when x < 0:
    ...
    break;
  case 0 when a > 5 && x == 0:
    ...
    break;
}
```

The use of dummy expressions (`(0)` in the switch, and `case 0`) is absolutely terrible, and I'd hate for it to become an idiom, but hey - it's concise and very clear. For sure it's not some hack that completely obscures the meaning and needs arcane knowledge, but C# would do well to obviate the need for it. I'd like the following to be legal:

```
switch                   // maybe () here, if the grammar would demand
{
  case when x < 0:       // I like the case to stay
    ...
  case when a > 5 && x == 0:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why is it terrible? It is already an idiom in many functional programming languages. Scala, Kotlin, F# all support guards during pattern matching. Often it is more convenient than simple if/else because you can simultaneously do field extraction

Comment: @paulpdaniels The guards are what we're after, obviously - that's the whole point. But the `switch(0)` and `case 0` - not so much. Scala, Kotlin and F# don't require a dummy expression to do condition mapping.