# How to return KB, MB and GB from Bytes using a public function

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, unit-conversion

I'm writing a "function" that returns a file's size (in B, KB, MB, GB).

The VB.Net code always gets the size in bytes first, so when a file's size (in Bytes) is less than 100 it returns B, if its > 1000 then I divide it by 1000 and it returns KB. But when it should be MB I try dividing by 1000000 and the size it returns always comes out 2 MBs bigger than what it should be!?

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong!!

#### Example

My files size is (15,570,550 Bytes) ..which is.. (14.8 MB)

So when i run it through this function it returns 16MB!

#### The Code

```
Public Function GetFileSize(ByVal TheFile As String, _
                            Optional ByVal ShowSizeType As Boolean = False) As String
    If TheFile.Length = 0 Then Return ""
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(TheFile) Then Return ""
    '---
    Dim TheSize As Integer = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(TheFile).Length
    Dim SizeType As String = ""
    '---
    If TheSize < 1000 Then
        SizeType = "B"
    Else
        If TheSize < 1000000000 Then
            If TheSize < 1000000 Then
                SizeType = "KB"
                TheSize = TheSize / 1000
            Else
                SizeType = "MB"
                TheSize = TheSize / 1000000
            End If
        Else
            SizeType = "GB"

        End If
    End If
    '---
    If ShowSizeType = True Then
        Return TheSize & SizeType
    Else
        Return TheSize
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Computers use binary. `Binary = Base 2`...`Decimal = Base 10`. You should be using `2^x`...

Comment: Read what others have posted, but to answer your specific question: it's rounding `15570550/1000000` which is 15.57 up to 16 to store it in your integer variable.

Comment: Do as roryap said. Divide it by 1024. Also, to make the code a little more simple, use `(1024 ^ 2)` for example instead of calculating it like `1 048 576`. AND if you want the output to have a decimal, you can declare `TheSize` as a decimal instead and use `TheSize = Math.Round(TheSize / (1024 ^ 2), 1)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use a select case for it and not a if.
And always start with the biggest size." i stopped at TB but of Corse you can add more if you need ..."

I changed Dim TheSize As Integer to "Dim TheSize As ULong " otherwise big numbers don't work.

Also make a dim "Dim DoubleBytes As Double" you will use it in the select case.

First you compare the bytes you have with a case , lets say mb "Case 1048576 To 1073741823" 
So if this is the case convert TheSize to a double "DoubleBytes = CDbl(TheSize / 1048576) 'MB
"

Then in the return you use FormatNumber to set the number you want to show behind the . "the nuber 2 is to set it to 2 behind the . like 28.11 , change it to 0 and it will return 28" also because you know it mb you wil add & mb to the return.
"Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " MB"
"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(GetFileSize("E:\Software\TeamSpeak3-Client-win64-3.0.14.exe"))
End Sub

Dim DoubleBytes As Double

Public Function GetFileSize(ByVal TheFile As String) As String
    If TheFile.Length = 0 Then Return ""
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(TheFile) Then Return ""
    '---
    Dim TheSize As ULong = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(TheFile).Length
    Dim SizeType As String = ""
    '---

    Try
        Select Case TheSize
            Case Is >= 1099511627776
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(TheSize / 1099511627776) 'TB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " TB"
            Case 1073741824 To 1099511627775
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(TheSize / 1073741824) 'GB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " GB"
            Case 1048576 To 1073741823
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(TheSize / 1048576) 'MB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " MB"
            Case 1024 To 1048575
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(TheSize / 1024) 'KB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " KB"
            Case 0 To 1023
                DoubleBytes = TheSize ' bytes
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " bytes"
            Case Else
                Return ""
        End Select
    Catch
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

---

I made a dll for it.
Then I can import it to my project and I can call it whenever I need to change a byte number to something else "like mb etc"
FormatBytes(GetHDSizeF) "GetHDSizeF is the number of bytes"

```
Dim DoubleBytes As Double
Default Public Property FormatBytes(ByVal BytesCaller As ULong) As String
    Get
        Try
            Select Case BytesCaller
                Case Is >= 1099511627776
                    DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1099511627776) 'TB
                    Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " TB"
                Case 1073741824 To 1099511627775
                    DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1073741824) 'GB
                    Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " GB"
                Case 1048576 To 1073741823
                    DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1048576) 'MB
                    Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " MB"
                Case 1024 To 1048575
                    DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1024) 'KB
                    Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " KB"
                Case 0 To 1023
                    DoubleBytes = BytesCaller ' bytes
                    Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " bytes"
                Case Else
                    Return ""
            End Select
        Catch
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Get
    Set(value As String)

    End Set
End Property
```

---

And if you don't want to make a dll you can use it like a normal function like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(FormatBytes(2000))
End Sub

Dim DoubleBytes As Double
Public Function FormatBytes(ByVal BytesCaller As ULong) As String

    Try
        Select Case BytesCaller
            Case Is >= 1099511627776
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1099511627776) 'TB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " TB"
            Case 1073741824 To 1099511627775
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1073741824) 'GB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " GB"
            Case 1048576 To 1073741823
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1048576) 'MB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " MB"
            Case 1024 To 1048575
                DoubleBytes = CDbl(BytesCaller / 1024) 'KB
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " KB"
            Case 0 To 1023
                DoubleBytes = BytesCaller ' bytes
                Return FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2) & " bytes"
            Case Else
                Return ""
        End Select
    Catch
        Return ""
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to divide by 1024 not 1000.  1 KB is not 1000 Bytes, it's 1024 bytes.  1 MB is not 1000 KB, it's 1024 KB, and so on.

Here's a good site to explain all this: http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/why_1024_bytes

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it, below is a VBA function that I use in Microsoft Access that can easily be converted to VB or VBScript, etc.

```
Public Function FormatFileSize(ByVal lngFileSize As Long) As String

  Dim x      As Integer:      x = 0
  Dim Suffix As String:  Suffix = ""
  Dim Result As Single:  Result = lngFileSize

  Do Until Int(Result) < 1000
     x = x + 1
     Result = Result / 1024
  Loop

  Result = Round(Result, 2)

  Select Case x
         Case 0
              Suffix = "Bytes"
         Case 1 'KiloBytes
              Suffix = "KB"
         Case 2 'MegaBytes
              Suffix = "MB"
         Case 3 'GigaBytes
              Suffix = "GB"
         Case 4 'TeraBytes
              Suffix = "TB"
         Case 5 'PetaBytes
              Suffix = "PB"
         Case 6 'ExaBytes
              Suffix = "EB"
         Case 7 'ZettaBytes
              Suffix = "ZB"
         Case 8 'YottaBytes
              Suffix = "YB"
         Case Else
              Suffix = "Too big to compute :)"
  End Select

  FormatFileSize = Format(Result, "#,##0.00") & " " & Suffix

End Function 'FormatFileSize
```

Comment: This is way better than a select case. This works the same way you might do on paper.

Answer (score 3):

this post helped me out when I was trying to sort this out Learning C#, I usually use VB. Anyway I thought I'd post my update in case anyone cares to use it.
It is in VB as I have a library of useful Functions and Subs that I use to keep this stuff in, And I started it in VB and too lazy to change all that code. It works well for me, so I hope it helps someone out.

```
Function ByteConv(Bytes As Double, Optional Style As Integer = 1) As String

    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim factor As Integer = 1024
    Dim Workingnum As Double = Bytes
    Dim Suffix() As String = {"Bytes", "Kb", "Mb", "Tb", "Pb", "Eb"} 'Dimention the string array upto Exobyte .. Cos why not?'

    If Style - 1 Then factor = 1000 Else factor = 1024  'This allows for Function to be used for Comms Calculations. I.e So it returns 100MB connection rather than 95.37'

    While Workingnum > factor And count < 5             'Basically keep dividing the Bytecount by the factor until the result reaches a whole number less that the factor itself'
        Workingnum = Workingnum / factor                ' '
        count = count + 1
    End While
    Return Workingnum.ToString("N") + Suffix(count)     ' Then return a string that includes the result and the applicable suffix.'
End Function
```

Comment: Just to confirm, shouldn't `If Style - 1` be `If Style = -1` ? With `Option Strict On` you'll get an error otherwise. I rewrote that bit into a ternary (I like ternaries :P) `factor = If(intStyle = -1, 1000, 1024)`

Comment: Did you forget Gb in your Suffix() array?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what I meant in my comment:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim CalculatedSize As Decimal
        Dim TheSize As Long = Long.Parse(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Length)
        Dim SizeType As String = "B"

        If TheSize < 1024 Then
            CalculatedSize = TheSize

        ElseIf TheSize > 1024 AndAlso TheSize < (1024 ^ 2) Then 'KB
            CalculatedSize = Math.Round((TheSize / 1024), 2)
            SizeType = "KB"

        ElseIf TheSize > (1024 ^ 2) AndAlso TheSize < (1024 ^ 3) Then 'MB
            CalculatedSize = Math.Round((TheSize / (1024 ^ 2)), 2)
            SizeType = "MB"

        ElseIf TheSize > (1024 ^ 3) AndAlso TheSize < (1024 ^ 4) Then 'GB
            CalculatedSize = Math.Round((TheSize / (1024 ^ 3)), 2)
            SizeType = "GB"

        ElseIf TheSize > (1024 ^ 4) Then 'TB
            CalculatedSize = Math.Round((TheSize / (1024 ^ 4)), 2)
            SizeType = "TB"

        End If

        MessageBox.Show("File size is: " & CalculatedSize.ToString & " " & SizeType, "File size", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image: File Sizes example]

Answer (score 0):

```
  Public Function GetDirSize(RootFolder As String) As Long
        Dim FolderInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(RootFolder)
        For Each File In FolderInfo.GetFiles : TotalSize += File.Length
        Next
        For Each SubFolderInfo In FolderInfo.GetDirectories : GetDirSize(SubFolderInfo.FullName)
        Next
        Return TotalSize
    End Function

    Public Sub GetfilesizeFromDirectory()
        Dim path As String
        path = "D:"
        TotalSize = 0 'Reset the counter
        Dim TheSize As Long = GetDirSize(path)
        ' TextBox1.Text = (FormatNumber(TheSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1) & vbCr & "MB")
    End Sub
```