# Can I use a variable in a switch statement?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, console-application

I am coding a text based adventure, and am having a problem. I am trying to make a switch statement case that handles every examination action you want, and am getting this for my code so far:

```
case "examine" + string x:
    //this is a method that I made that makes sure that it is an object in the area
    bool iseobj = tut.Check(x);
    if (iseobj)
        x.examine();
    else
        Console.WriteLine("That isn't an object to examine");
    break;
```

How do I use a variable in my `case` statement? I want any string starting with "examine" + (x) to trigger the case.

Comment: You mean you want this as an variable `Console.WriteLine("That isn't an object to examine");` ?

Comment: cases in switch statement must be constant. it cannot contain variables

Comment: I edited your question to be more clear, let me know if I understood it correctly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your scenario would fit into an `if-else` statement better than a `switch` statement. In C#, a `switch` can [only evaluate values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554693/3191599), not expressions. This means you **can't** do:

```
case input.StartsWith("examine"):
```

However, you can make this work with an `if` statement! Consider doing the following:

```
if (input.StartsWith("examine"))
{
    //this is a method that I made that makes sure that it is an object in the area
    bool iseobj = tut.Check(x);
    if (iseobj)
        x.examine();
    else
        Console.WriteLine("That isn't an object to examine");
}
else if (...) // other branches here
```

Comment: Should `case StartsWith(` read `case input.StartsWith(` ?  Otherwise jolly good answer

Comment: @MickyD Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @Fireball175 If you want to get your `x` variable you could do `string x = s.Split(new[] { "examine" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]` inside the `if`.

Comment: @ArthurRey it says string doesn't contain a defenition for 'examine', any ideas?

Comment: @Fireball175 x being a `string`, the `x.examine()` will fail.

Comment: @ArthurRey figuring out how to fix it, but thankyou so much for the help, I really appreciate it.