# Is it possible to optimize these if-else statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization

**I am new to C#** and curious if there is some kind of better structure for this code:

---

This code determines the real month from *Czech Birth Number* = personal identification number in the Czech republic. Numbers there are constant.

```cs
private ushort RawMonth
// get raw integer month code without resolving it
{
    get { return Convert.ToUInt16(SanitizedBirthNumberString.Substring(2, 2)); }
}


if (RawMonth >= 01 && RawMonth <= 12)
{
    return RawMonth;
}
else if (RawMonth >= 51 && RawMonth <= 62)
{
    return RawMonth - 50;
}
else if (RawMonth >= 21 && RawMonth <= 32)
{
    return RawMonth - 20;
}
else if (RawMonth >= 71 && RawMonth <= 82)
{
    return RawMonth - 70;
}
else
{
    // just some of my custom exceptions
    throw new MonthCodeInvalidException();
}
```

---

Is it just me? Because those `if`-`else` statements look deprecated. Thank you.

---

I had to make a few major adjustments, starting with setting the C# language version to 9.0.

But eventually, I have this code, it compiles, I just never used such syntax, please check after me, thank you.

```cs
public ushort ResolvedMonth
{
    get => RawMonth switch
    {
         >= 01 and <= 12 => RawMonth,
         >= 21 and <= 32 => (ushort)(RawMonth - 20),
         >= 51 and <= 62 => (ushort)(RawMonth - 50),
         >= 71 and <= 82 => (ushort)(RawMonth - 70),
         _ => throw new MonthCodeInvalidException()
    };
}
```

---

Interestingly enough, for it to run, I had to use typecast, have no idea why... But anyway - looks much neater.

Note: It uses [C# 9.0 introduced Relational patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#relational-patterns) (link to MS C# reference).

Comment: It's not the if statements that are strange here. What does `rawMonth` mean? Why can it be larger than 12? If you explain what this should do, maybe a better solution is possible.

Comment: Put all those triplets (1,12,0), (51,62,50) ...  into an auxiliary table and do a for over the table

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for improving working code - ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: What's Czech Birth Number? Full statement of the problem might help. But if there is no pattern there - just use if-else, no need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Well that's not an explanation we need. I mean something like "the 3 and 4th digits of it represent a month, and that is what `RawMonth` is in my example. For women, 50 is added to the month number, for men it's just plain month number".

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: @TobySpeight Ok, Toby, will do, if I decide to post there.

Comment: You can simplify this solution by using an [expression bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), removing the temp variable and removing parentheses: `public ushort ResolvedMonth => RawMonth switch { >=1 and <=12 => RawMonth, ... };`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Ok, sir, will try later on, right now, I'm trying to determine how the first solution even works, give me time, thank you!

Comment: This solution uses a switch expression together with [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) (link includes a switch expression example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them hard coded, and your inputs generally won't have bad values in, you could pattern match in increasing order:

```
RawMonth switch
{
  <=12 => RawMonth,
  <=32 => RawMonth-20,
  <=62 => RawMonth-50,
  <=82 => RawMonth-70,
  _ => throw ...
}
```

If you'll have bad input and need the ranges:

```
RawMonth switch
{
  (>=1) and (<=12) => RawMonth,
  (>=21) and (<=32) => RawMonth-20,
  (>=51) and (<=62) => RawMonth-50,
  (>=71) and (<=82) => RawMonth-70
    _ => throw ...
}
```

The parentheses are optional; I find it helps readability but your opinion may vary!

It's a shame that the number pattern isn't more consistent (eg if the 20 range actually started at 30), as you could have just eg modded them by 20, but I suppose you could decrement by 10 or 20 until they come into range

```
if(RawMonth>40)
  RawMonth -= 10;

while(RawMonth>12)
  RawMonth -= 20;

if(RawMonth < 1)
  throw ...

return RawMonth;
```

I think that's the logic (though I didn't put any >82 check in)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NBgmyf - apologies for the indentation; on a cellphone and the editor doesn't really play ball with it

Comment: You made my day, this is what I consider _neat_. Thanks again, sir.

Comment: If you're asking why you have to do a cast, it's because you have subtracted some integer from RawMonth. I suppose RawMonth is a ushort; because you've subtracted eg int 70 from it, it makes the result an int. there isn't a way of specifying the 70 to be a ushort other than somewhere else putting eg `ushort SEVENTY = 70; and using the variable instead. Probably easier to just make RawMonth and ResolvedMonth as int

Comment: If you don't want to make it an interesting you can't get away from the cast but you can do just one; cast the whole `RawMonth switch{...}` to a ushort eg `get => (ushort)(RawMonth switch...);`

Answer (score 1):

In principle there is nothing wrong with `if .. else if .. else` (for a few cases like yours). But you can also create a list of tuples with the lower and upper bounds and the respective decrement value and then search for the correct tuple in that list.

```
//create a list with lower and upper limits and the respective decrement value
var limits = new List<(int, int, int)> {
    (1, 12, 0),  //lower limit, upper limit, decrement value
    (21, 32, 20),
    (51, 62, 50),
    (71, 82, 70)
};
    
var rawmonth = 23;
//find the respective interval for your given rawmonth
var d = limits.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1 <= rawmonth && x.Item2 >= rawmonth);

//if nothing is found, d will be (0,0,0)
if (d.Item1 == 0)
  throw new YourCustomException();

//substract the respective decrementvalue
rawmonth -= d.Item3;
```

Comment: If you put labels in your `List<(int,int,int)>` you could use them instead of Item1/2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest naming the integers if they have meanings, to don't have magic numbers that are hard to read and understand by others

When I find myself with something similar, I put the conditions in delegates in a Dictionary and in the method I try to get the matching by Key and return the Value from Dictionary if nothing exist return the default

I have attached a link that demonstrates my point [Avoid If Statements](https://medium.com/swlh/effective-dictionary-usage-c-avoid-if-statements-80595aac68d5)

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch statement as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54401172/939213) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49624848/939213).

The first link's style:

```
switch (RawMonth)
{
    case int n when n >= 01 && n <= 12:
        ...
        break;
    case int n when n >= 51 && n <= 62:
        ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's a curious construct isn't it? It's more wordy than just aliasing RawMonth as n and using if else ..

Answer (score 0):

The first thing if-else statement is not depreciated. You can keep it as it is. You can also use a switch statement with expression.

```
    int output = RawMonth switch
            {
                int Month when Month >= 01 && Month <= 12 => Month,
                int Month when Month >= 51 && Month <= 62 => Month - 50,
                int Month when Month >= 71 && Month <= 82 => Month - 70,
                _ => throw new Exception("th")
            };
return output ;
```

Above code can be even simplified to

```
        int output = RawMonth switch
        {
            >= 01 and <= 12 => RawMonth,
            >= 51 and  <= 62 => RawMonth - 50,
            >= 71 and  <= 82 => RawMonth - 70,
            _ => throw new Exception("th")
        };
```